# Angular Circular Dependency Solution

Tags: javascript, angular, circular-dependency

- I have `popupservice` that opens popup components for me like this:

  ```
  export class PopupService {
      alert() { this.matdialog.open(PopupAlertComponent); }
      yesno() { this.matdialog.open(PopupYesNoComponent); }
      custom() { this.matdialog.open(PopupCustomComponent); }
  }
  ```
- Then I open my custom popup with `this.popupservice.custom()`.

  ```
  export class HomeComponent {
      constructor(private popupservice: PopupService) {}
      openCustomPopup() {
           this.popupservice.custom();
      }
  }
  ```
- Then, in my `custom` popup component I want to call my own `alert` popup (to report an error or something):

  ```
  export class CustomPopup {
      constructor(private popupservice: PopupService) {}
      doHttpCall() {
           ...do http calls...
           if (callFailed) this.popupservice.alert('Call Failed');
      }
  }
  ```

**How can I solve this circular dependency problem?**

**Notes:**

- I have read the other questions but I feel that my problem is a specific "help me out" problem. Though you are still welcome to refer me to other questions.
- The `this.popupservice.alert()` is not just a javascript `alert`, it is my own custom popup that has a theme and everything.

Comment: Can you post some code for DI

Comment: That 3rd party popup needs component reference to create the popup, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes exactly :) `this.matdialog.open(PopupAlert);`

Comment: Posted an answer, check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to take away popup creation logic from `PopupService`. Here is a little refactor for you.

Use `PopupService` to only create events from different parts of the application.

```js
@Injectable()
export class PopupService {
    private _alert: Subject<any> = new Subject();
    private _yesno: Subject<any> = new Subject();
    private _custom: Subject<any> = new Subject();

    // since you didn't like the on- methods, you can do following
    public readonly alert$ = this._alert.asObservable();
    public readonly yesno$ = this._yesno.asObservable();
    public readonly custom$ = this._custom.asObservable();

    onAlert() { return this._alert.asObservable(); }

    onYesno() { return this._yesno.asObservable(); }

    onCustom() { return this._custom.asObservable(); }

    alert(payload) { this._alert.next(payload); }
    yesno(payload) { this._yesno.next(payload); }
    custom(payload) { this._custom.next(payload); }
}
```

So, we have a `PopupService` which only emits some events with some `payload`s. I used `Subject` here because later subscribers won't need to know if there was a `alert` or `yesno` event earlier. If you want to have such logic, you can change `Subject` to `BehaviorSubject`.

Create a component called `PopupManager` and use it in `app.component`

`app.component.ts`

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <!-- some template -->
        <app-popup-manager></app-popup-manager>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

```js
@Component({
   selector: 'app-popup-manager',
   template: '' // don't need to have template
})
export class PopupManagerComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private matDialog: MatDialog, private popupService: PopupService) {}

   ngOnInit() {
       this.popupService.onAlert().subscribe(payload => {
       //   this.matDialog.open...
       });

       this.popupService.onYesno().subscribe(payload => {
       //   this.matDialog.open...
       });

       this.popupService.onCustom().subscribe(payload => {
       //   this.matDialog.open...
       });
   }
}
```

With this way, you can use PopupService in any component you want since it is a singleton, standalone service now.

**Why you should not expose `Subject`s to outside world?**

You can think of this encapsulating class fields. You could indeed expose `_alert` to outside world but then you will have no control over who uses this subject in what way. Methods are always great way to provide functionality while maintaining some control over the fields. In the future, you may want to change internals of the service, maybe some of the subjects. If you let other parts of the application access directly on fields, you would have to refactor a lot. But this way, since you are giving them some methods, as long as you don't break those methods you'll be fine.

Comment: Dude this is perfect thank you! But you can remove the onX() functions right? Then in PopupManagerComponent just use `this.popupService._alert.subscribe(...)`

Comment: You should not access to subject directly, I'll put an alternative way to do it.

Comment: Why should you not? You are returning the observable anyway so I feel like you can just skip the return function and access it directly. Why is this not a good idea?

Comment: It is like having `private` fields. You should encapsulate the subject and only let people emit events through `methods`.

Comment: I'll explain why you should hide `Subject`s.

Comment: Either way you solved the solution perfectly so I am just trying to learn why it is done your way (in my eyes it seems unnecessary)

Comment: @FreddyBonda explained why you should hide the fields. Also, provided a way to expose subjects to outside without defining methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184376/discussion-between-freddy-bonda-and-bunyamin-coskuner).

Answer (score 2):

Your service should not know about components, that is bad design if your services have knowledge of components. You should have an observable like a behaviour subject in your service and have your component subscribe to the observable to know when to popup a new message.

In your service

```
message$ = new BehaviourSubject<string>(null);
```

and a function to send a message down the pipeline.

```
nextMessage(message: string) {
  this.message$.next(message);
}
```

Then in your component you subscribe to the message$ observable and then do you popup.

```
this.messageSubscription = this.service.message$.subscribe(message => { this.popup(message); });
```

Making sure to takeUntil or unscbscribe on ngDestroy.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.messageSubscription ) {
    this.messageSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the popup listen to the observable and then open it self? I don't fully understand this. Would you mind putting your code into the PopupService, HomeComponent & CustomPopup **please**. That would help a lot!